# Filter Illuminate collection based on emptiness of child collection

Tags: php, laravel

Orders implements a HasManyThrough relationship to Items.  I want to filter the Orders collection to ones just the orders that have zero items.  I tried:

```php
$orders->where('items', '!=', []);
```

This of course doesn't work as it's only possible to do discrete comparisons (equal, not equal, less/greater than, etc) against concrete values.  There is no "isEmpty" property.  Something like a `whereCallback` would be super.

What would be the easiest way to perform this?  The same `$orders` collection is already used in multiple ways in the same request, so I'd rather not do another roundtrip to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter) is kind of like the `whereCallback` you're looking for.

```
$ordersWithoutItems = $orders->filter(function($order) {
    return $order->items()->doesntExist();
});
```

Comment: `$order->items()` this uses another roundtrip to the database, which he wants to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you include the `items_count` to the `orders` collection while fetching it from the database.

```
$orders = Order::withCount('items')->restOfTheQuery()->get();
```

this will add another property called `items_count` to each and every `order` object in the `$orders` collection

and then, when you want only the `orders` which doesn't have `items`

```
// using collections where function
$orderWithoutItems = $orders->where('items_count', 0);
```

Comment: I agree, this seems like a better way to do it.